# Dismissing WKWebView when navigating to a specific URL

Tags: swiftui

I am currently using WKWebView to load an HTML file rather than an URL, and I'm looking for a way to dismiss the sheet when the user navigates to a specific URL.

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var text: String
   
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    return WKWebView()
  }
   
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    uiView.loadHTMLString(text, baseURL: nil)
  }
}
```

I am using this UIViewRepresentable to load the HTML string, and I am using this sheet to display the WebView:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented, onDismiss: {
            self.checkthreed()
        }, content: {
            WebView(text: $decodedString) 
        })
```

The user can navigate to 2 URLs:

- example.com/failure
- example.com/success

How can I dismiss the sheet when the user navigates to either of these URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic very that you can adjust to fit your needs:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var closeFunction : (() -> Void)?
   
    class Coordinator : NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var closeFunction : (() -> Void)?
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            if let urlStr = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString {
                if urlStr == "test" {
                    closeFunction?()
                }
            }
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    return WKWebView()
  }
   
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
    context.coordinator.closeFunction = closeFunction
    uiView.loadHTMLString(text, baseURL: nil)
  }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sheetPresented = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi")
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheetPresented, content: {
                WebView(text: .constant("<a href=\"test\">Test link</a><br><a href=\"test2\">Test 2</a>"),
                        closeFunction: {
                            sheetPresented = false
                        })
            })
        }
}
```

The `WKWebView` gets a `WKNavigationDelegate` attached to it where it can receive notifications about what URL is being loaded. You can see in my example that "test" triggers the close while "test2" does not.

The `WKNavigationDelegate` is part of a `Coordinator` for the `UIViewRepresentable`.  Note that I made `closeFunction` an optional closure, so you have to make sure to set it, or nothing will happen. Another route to take would be to pass the `Binding<Bool>` for the sheet being presented and manipulate that directly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This solution will most likely solve my problem, but I couldn't  figure out how to set `closeFunction`. How should I do it?

Comment: I was using it as a trailing closure on WebView, which wasn't very clear. I've updated my sample so you can see it is a named parameter when you create `WebView` in `ContentView`